# Opencl Program do nothing but host has overhead

Tags: opencl, wait, host, overhead

I have a very simple program using opencl:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

int main(){
    getchar();
    cl_int error;
    cl_uint platforms;
    cl_platform_id platform;

    error=clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, &platforms);
    if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("\n Error number %d", error);
    }
    else
    printf("OK\n");

    return 1;
}
```

I copmpile it with
`g++ overhead_tan.cpp -o overhead_tan -lOpenCL`
The program works, but with very big overhead! When I start the program, it would have to wait with no CPU resources. Wouldn't it? But the result is here:

```
Threads:
  1  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||                          42.7%]
  2  [|                                                   0.7%]
  3  [||||||||||||||||||||||                             37.9%]
  4  [||                                                  1.3%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||                         1476/5929MB]
```

(Before I launch the program all thread loaded ~1%) And it shows me that the kernel runs there.

Why is that overhead?

Comment: What have you used to take that measurement? What point in the program execution does it correspond to? Once `getchar` has received some input, the program exits almost immediately.

Comment: It can't be, 42% CPU 1 line of OpenCL API? BTW that usage is showing multiple threads working. You are definitely doing something wrong in the measurement.

Comment: That's not hard to be. You're collecting list of OpenCL platforms - that means, you make calls to drivers, load libraries, etc. That's a lot of work to do, especially if you have multiple platforms.

Comment: NOOOO!
The program is waiting at getchar(); !!!! So that's what I dont understand! It is doing nothing!!